# Invalid syntax in Python code (.replace() and for loop)

Tags: python

I have been having problems using the .replace() method and for loop. My code below:

```
K=int(input("How many times do you want to input? "))
print("K> "+str(K))
my_list=['A']
count=0
while count<K:
    letter.replace('A','B').replace('B','B'+'A') for letter in my_list
    print(my_list)
    count=count+1
```

The letter.replace() results in an invalid syntax error and I was wondering how to resolve this.
I also have been having problems replacing the 'A' with 'B'. Would implementing the for loop work?

Comment: What is the error which is coming?

Comment: I am trying to find each 'letter' in the list and then based on that replace it with 'B' if it is 'A' and 'B' and 'A' if it is 'B'. The letter is supposed to be each letter in my_list

Comment: Do you want to loop over the list again and again?

Comment: Heh. That looks like an attempt at Perl syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to iterate over the list K no. of times. I have used for loop and if condition.

```
K=int(input("How many times do you want to input? "))
print("K> "+str(K))
my_list=['A']
count=0
while count<K:
    for value in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[value]=='A':
            my_list[value]='B'
        elif my_list[value]=='B':
            my_list[value]='BA'
    print(my_list)
    count+=1
```

Output:

```
How many times do you want to input? 3
K> 3
['B']
['BA']
['BA']
```